# как правильно применить docker-compose вместо нескольких контейнеров

Tags: php, nginx, развертывание, docker, docker-compose

хочу развернуть на локальном компьютере нужное мне окружение из php+nginx+mysql

в docker-compose.yml описываю все эти сервисы и один создаю общий контейнер (chat) который линкует все сервисы

```
chat:
  build: build/chat
  ports:
    - "80"
  links:
    - mysql
    - php
    - nginx
  volumes:
    - var/www:/var/www
nginx:
  image: nginx
  volumes:
    - etc/nginx:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
mysql:
  image: mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: yes
php:
  image: php:fpm
```

в Dockerfile почти ничего пока нету, это заготовка

```
FROM ubuntu
```

**Проблема**

при запуске `docker-compose up -d`
подымаются все сервисы кроме chat
`docker-compose start` подымает chat и сразу завершается

Comment: `FORM ubuntu` — опечатка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker довольно сложная для быстрого вхождения технология, но через некоторое время все встанет на свои места.

Концепция Docker - один процесс в одном контейнере. При завершении команды конейнера последний прекращает свою активность и уходит в остановленные контейнеры. Docker-compose при этом предполагает, что с его помощью поднимаются сервисы, которые **не должны выходить вообще никогда**. Если сервис прекратил свое существование, то значит он умер, сгнил и протух, и вся композиция должна умереть вместе с ним. Таким образом, когда умирает chat, а умирает он сразу же - в ubuntu не заведено условно-бесконечной команды - умирает и вообще все.

Как это исправить - выкинуть вообще chat. Он не нужен, корневым контейнером должен быть nginx, который должен проexpose'ить свои порты наружу композиции, а все остальные контейнеры должны так или иначе предоставлять ему свои возможности.

Я сильно не рекомендую использовать volumes без надобности, volume - это либо место для постоянного хранения, либо место для временного размещения файлов на время выполнения операции внутренним сервисом контейнера (например, так используют composer). И то, и то нужно избегать, у вас же вообще маппятся абсолютные пути, словно share mount, и композиция становится непереносима.

Comment: - chat мне нужен, так как в нем будет основной код сайта (верней mount наружу) и при билде будет устанавливаться дополнительные зависимости
- как раз сейчас композиция переносимая, полные пути у меня только внтури контейнеров, а относительные в хосте (./etc, ./build и ./var/www)


Я еще копал и вроде бы понял,
- что chat нужно добавить tty:true, тогда он не умирает
- заменить mount host на mount_from chat
- заменить ports на expose

Comment: сори, не могу отредактировать выше указанный комент, но хотел еще добавить первопричину такого разделения.
Я хотел бы иметь возможность запускать проект на разных контейнерах, например вместо php использовать hhvm, а вместо nginx - apache. Compose мне помогает сделать это декларативно, причем  брать оригинальные сервисы и если нужно немного добавлять им функционала. Например в php я могу декларативно добавить экстеншены, или до установить композер. И вроде как в голове картина складывается, но нюансы которые я с трудом понимаю с английского мне мешают дореализовать мою мысль

Comment: "chat мне нужен, так как в нем будет основной код сайта" - слушайте, ну вот серьезно. У меня есть некоторый опыт. Я на его основе говорю: это вам не нужно. Потому что код должен валяться там, где он будет исполняться - в php-fpm. Добавив tty:true, вы убьете весь смысл системы, и одному богу демонов известно, как она будет вести себя в бекграунде. Троллейбус из буханки на самом деле не может ездить.

Comment: вы предлагаете замапить код в контейнер с php, и когда понадобиться hhvm то замапить и туда. Чем это отличаеться от отдельный сервис сайта, отдельный сервис интерпретатора, отдельный сервис базы данных. И настраивать линки в том контейнере который разрабатываеться, в моем случае это chat. Я так понял философия docker это выделит сервис в отдельный контейнер

Comment: Я не предлагаю ничего мапить, я предлагаю его туда положить, если контейнер должен распространяться с исходным кодом, то это уже не контейнер. Приложение само по себе является сервисом.

Comment: наверно я вас не понимаю, поэтому задам конкретные вопросы, по именно моему случаю.

1) Чем плохо/хорошо иметь отдельный контейнер который будет `mount /var/www:/var/www`, в котором будет  Dockerfile c описанием деплоя, и в этом деплое будут использоваться сервисы база данных и php.

2) Чем плохо/хорошо иметь контейнер в который базируеться на php:fpm, в котором будет деплой сайта(chat), который будет mount /var/www и который будет использовать сервис баз данных

Comment: сори я выше писал mount, но подразумевал volumes. Просто мне кажется что именно это делает volumes. Черт неудобно когда сервис не дает редактировать мне свои же сообщения

Comment: Я уже писал про volumes, они здесь не нужны, их нужно избегать. Потому что они размещаются совсем не в контейнерах, и их реальная область применения довольно узкая, и к ней такие задачи не относятся. Плохо иметь такой контейнер тупо потому, что он не сервис и не выполняет никакой работы, потому он и не нужен. Приложение и должно быть отнаследованным от php-fpm, только внутри контейнера нет никакого деплоя. Файлы попадают внутрь при создании образа (при выполнении build), и ничего после этого туда не попадает.